# Perfectly flat surface

Tags: microscopy

Looking at microscopic images of work tops I noticed that none are perfectly flat.
Is it possible to actually create a perfectly flat surface?

[image]

Comment: how about this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMByI4s-D-Y

Comment: To within one atomic layer? Yes. Search for methods to create atomically flat gold or silicon.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "surface" I suppose. If you mean general work surface then I don't know. I do know of at least one purportedly "perfectly flat" material though, due to the geometric arrangement of it's atoms:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mica

Comment: Perhaps also see the excellently named https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleavage_%28crystal%29

Comment: Leaving out the concept of "flatness" at lengths smaller than atoms, of course.  Those pesky Brownian motions and electron orbital probabilities ensure nothing is ever flat :-)